# Dynamic label and cell height with show more button action

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I am trying to implement dynamic label height in a `tableViewCell` after clicking show more button label needs to set `label.numberOfLines = 0`.

Then cell height and label height should increase dynamically.

Here is my code below (when `tableView` reloads the same label height taking for reused cell)

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

 let cell: UITableViewCell = 
 self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: 
 "BTSTableViewCellIdentifier")! 
    cell.configureWithPost(posts[indexPath.row])
    cell.delegate = self
    return cell
   }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: 
  IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt 
 indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}


func configureWithPost(_ postViewModel: BTSTableCellViewModel) {
    self.postViewModel = postViewModel
    usernameLabel.text = postViewModel.username
    detailtextLabel.numberOfLines = 2
    detailtextLabel.text = postViewModel.textDetail  
}

@IBAction func showmorePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    detailtextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
         self.tableView.reload()

}
```

Comment: return the `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` at height for row at index path when its is pressed ViewMore  else return some static height

Comment: @Bharath issue fixed?

Comment: I have already implemented height for the row. But still, i am getting the issue. @Ganesh

Comment: @Bharath Are you using swift 3 ? then tableview.reloadData it should be....Also check if showMorePressed acton is getting called by putting breakpoints.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to manage height in heightForRowAtIndexPath :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }
```

Also in showMore Button Action,

```
@IBAction func showmorePressed(_ sender: Any) {
    detailtextLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
         self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same problem. Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize boundingBox = [label.text boundingRectWithSize:constraint
                                              options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:label.font}
                                              context:context].size;

size = CGSizeMake(ceil(boundingBox.width), ceil(boundingBox.height));
```